# Вычисления на GPU Amd

Tags: c#, amd

С помощью какой библиотеки можно проводить математические вычисления на GPU от Amd ?

Comment: [OpenCL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL)

Comment: Далеко не все математические вычисления хорошо параллелятся так что вычисления на GPU превосходят CPU по скорости.

Comment: @ГеннадийП выше утверждение противоречит само себе. Либо вы не в курсе, как вычисления параллелятся на GPU.

Comment: @ГеннадийП - "Казнить нельзя помиловать". Без запятой в нужном месте ваша фраза может противоречить самой себе.